# Improving a Stack Exchange site, but with limited rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation

I have limited reputation (less than 1k) and can only:

1. Ask question
2. Answer question
3. flag content
4. edit content
5. vote to close / re-open / delete questions

What else can I do in order to improve a Stack Exchange site?

Are there some not-so-obvious things I can do, with limited reputation (less than 1k reputation)?

Comment: You can find all the privileges based on your reputation in the [help/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page.

Comment: Delete requires 10k rep, that's far from "limited". So not sure what you ask here. Please be more clear what you mean with "limited reputation".

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have edited; I had thought I saw an option on my end to cast delete votes for a SE site ... I forget which one, though ... but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Btw (2) gives you up to 1k reputation which is enough on most sites to access review queues as well.

Comment: "In my experience, most powerful moderation tool is given at really modest rep 5..." ([Why aren't moderation tools given to people with a history of good moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268115/839601))

Comment: Editing should be your top priority, assuming you are a good editor (and not just adding bold markup to words). It helps to clarify questions that can be either answered by you or others, it gives future visitors a much better impression of the quality of the site, find relevant posts more easily with a higher chance they want to contribute as well. On top of that it earns you some rep, bringing you closer to new privileges, like the review queues.

Comment: If you’re interested in spam removal, there’s [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org) (full disclosure: I’m a member).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you kind of covered everything the sites offer... Questions, answers, flagging, editing, voting, closing, reopening, deleting... did I miss one? Chatting (just kidding, chat doesn't benefit anyone).

I suppose you could use the review queues, but I had assumed that was related with your mention of flagging content, closing content, or editing content.

The best way to improve the site would be to simply improve the way you use it. Do more research for posting questions or answers, make more edits which significantly improve posts, help close questions that need closure either in the queues or through flagging from the newest list, vote on posts where you feel you can determine if the content is of use or not; increasing any of these activities will benefit the site indirectly, and if everyone were simply doing this the sites would greatly benefit.

Comment: *chat doesn't benefit anyone* ... you tell me now???

Comment: You see the thing about that is, I, uh, *runs*